# MS Access VBA equivalent to Ctrl+'?

Tags: vba, ms-access, copy, sendkeys

I am having a difficult time how to properly copy specific field data from previous records on my user form. I don't have a code sample to show but my request is very simplistic.

Currently, out of 12 fields, I have 6 that I often repeat data. I can click on and [press](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-access-70a673e4-4f7b-4300-b8e5-3320fa6606e2) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> ("Insert the value from the same field in the previous record") and it performs the task I want. However, it adds a lot of time to the task. I simply want to write VBA code to perform that command to those specific fields.

I haven't been able to get `SendKeys` to work. `DLast` appears to provide random data at times. I feel like this should be a very simple request but for some reason I am not finding a functional solution for it.

Comment: If you're using VBA why aren't you using a simple update query to repeat the data from previous records?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that it's a simple form to edit a simple table, and that the bound data field names match the control names, you may get away with

```vb
If Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition > 0 Then
  With Me.Recordset.Clone()
    .AbsolutePosition = Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition - 1
    
    Dim control_name As Variant
    For Each control_name In Array("field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5", "field6")
      Me.Controls(control_name).Value = .Fields(control_name).Value
    Next
  End With
End If
```

which you assign to a separate button on the same form.

Answer (score 1):

Don't fiddle with arrays or queries - use the *power of DAO*:

```vb
Private Sub CopyButton_Click()

    CopyRecord
    
End Sub
```

- If a record is selected, copy this.
- If a new record is selected, copy the last (previous) record.

```vb
Private Sub CopyRecord()
  
    Dim Source        As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Insert        As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Field         As DAO.Field
    
    ' Live recordset.
    Set Insert = Me.RecordsetClone
    ' Source recordset.
    Set Source = Insert.Clone
    
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        ' Copy the last record.
        Source.MoveLast
    Else
        ' Copy the current record.
        Source.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
    End If
  
    Insert.AddNew
    For Each Field In Source.Fields
        With Field
            If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
            Else
                Select Case .Name
                    ' List names of fields to copy.
                    Case "FirstField", "AnotherField", "YetAField"  ' etc.
                        ' Copy field content.
                        Insert.Fields(.Name).Value = Source.Fields(.Name).Value
                End Select
            End If
        End With
    Next
    Insert.Update
    
    Insert.Close
    Source.Close
    
End Sub
```

This also, by the way, is an excellent example of the difference between the `RecordsetClone` and the `Clone` of a recordset - the first being "the records of the form", while the second is an independant copy.

This also means, that the form will update *automatically* and *immediately*.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good idea post here already.

You could also say place a function in the before insert event. This event ONLY fires when you start typing into a NEW reocrd, and it becomes dirty.

So, maybe this:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)

   Dim rstPrevious     As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strSQL          As String
   
   strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblPeople ORDER BY ID DESC"
   
   Set rstPrevious = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
   
   ' auto file out some previous values
   
   If rstPrevious.RecordCount > 0 Then
   
     Me.Firstname = rstPrevious!Firstname
     Me.LastName = rstPrevious!LastName
           
  End If

End Sub
```

And some good ideas in say having a "list" or "array" of controls/fields to setup, so you don't have to write a lot of code. (as suggested in the other post/answer here)