# Ctrl+' for copying from previous record in MS Access not working bilingual in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, keyboard-shortcuts

Working bilingual, Shortcut Ctrl+' used to work for me for years in both languages (English and Hebrew), but not in 2016. Is there a way to make Ctrl+, (the second language equivalent of Ctrl+') do the same copy-from-previous-record action?
This is an all Access feature - not limited to a specific field or row or table or form or application.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Access VBA equivalent to Ctrl+'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72493052/ms-access-vba-equivalent-to-ctrl)